# How can I setup NSwag openapi2tsclient to generate correct Datetime init function?

Tags: typescript, openapi, nswag

I have a BE API (.NET 5.0) and FE in React. I am using NSwag to generate swagger.json file and then openapi2tsclient to convert it to typescript file. Everything works grate. I have a base entity with Datetime in UTC. It is translated to swagger.json file as:

```
"creationDate": {
     "type": "string",
     "format": "date-time"
},
```

This object is is initialized in my generated ts file like this:

```
export class BaseEntity implements IBaseEntity {
    id!: string;
    creationDate!: Date;
    modifiedDate!: Date;
    createdBy!: string;
    modifiedBy!: string;

    constructor(data?: IBaseEntity) {
        if (data) {
            for (var property in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(property))
                    (<any>this)[property] = (<any>data)[property];
            }
        }
    }

    init(_data?: any) {
        if (_data) {
            this.id = _data["id"];
            this.creationDate = _data["creationDate"] ? new Date(_data["creationDate"].toString()) : <any>undefined;
            this.modifiedDate = _data["modifiedDate"] ? new Date(_data["modifiedDate"].toString()) : <any>undefined;
            this.createdBy = _data["createdBy"];
            this.modifiedBy = _data["modifiedBy"];
        }
    }

    static fromJS(data: any): BaseEntity {
        data = typeof data === 'object' ? data : {};
        let result = new BaseEntity();
        result.init(data);
        return result;
    }

    toJSON(data?: any) {
        data = typeof data === 'object' ? data : {};
        data["id"] = this.id;
        data["creationDate"] = this.creationDate ? this.creationDate.toISOString() : <any>undefined;
        data["modifiedDate"] = this.modifiedDate ? this.modifiedDate.toISOString() : <any>undefined;
        data["createdBy"] = this.createdBy;
        data["modifiedBy"] = this.modifiedBy;
        return data; 
    }
}
```

But now my creationDate time is not longer in UTC but in GMT.

DateTime in DB: "2022-02-19 17:49:04.5360786"

Original time (as string from BE) before init: "2022-02-19T17:49:04.5360786"

creationDate after init function: Sat Feb 19 2022 17:49:04 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

For displaying time I am using [react-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment) package. When I don't use typescript and my datetime goes from BE as string I can use this code to display correct time:

```
<Moment utc local format="DD. MM. YYYY HH:mm">
   {item.creationDate}
</Moment>

19. 02. 2022 18:49 //correct time
```

But when I use typescript item. And my *creationDate* is no longer just string but converted Date I am getting wrong time:

```
19. 02. 2022 17:49 // not correct time
```

Is there a way how can I setup NSwag openapi2tsclient to generate correct typescript file? Or what is a solution to such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this is not correct representation of UTC time

```
"2022-02-19T17:49:04.5360786"
```

There should be a "Z" at the end of it.

```
"2022-02-19T17:49:04.5360786Z"
```

So my backend was sending correct UTC time but without Z at the end. When JS was trying to convert it to new Date() it assumes that it is not UTC time. I end up setting serialization of all outgoing Datetime to be UTC in Startup.cs by:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
            });
```

Now it is working correctly.